# How to color a sprite using Hue shifting. The right way to proceed

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, graphics, colors

My goal is to color a sprite, a complex image or photo using a base RGB input. Let's say `R: 100 G: 145 B: 23`.
The basic idea is that starting from an image which predominant color is let's say RED, I want a resulting image which predominant color is the input `RGB 100, 145, 23`.
This is how I want to color the image.
I decided to proceed this way:

1. Get the HUE of the input RGB Value.
2. Calculate the predominant color of the current image to modify
3. Get the HUE of the resulting predominant color
4. Shift the HUE with the difference between the input HUE and the image HUE
5. Game over

Is this a right way to proceed ? Or maybe there is a simpler way ?

Comment: Supposing you can select only the area with the (exact?) hue you are wanting to modify, this sounds like a fine plan.

Comment: What does it mean. What I wanna to do is to calculate the predominant color of the whole image, excluding the areas with alpha (transparent background)

Comment: Ah, I only now understand.  I'm not sure how you plan on doing step #2.  If you could make some assumptions about the way your image colors were distributed, you could sample from the total image for your averaging calculation instead of averaging every single pixel.

Comment: What do you mean with the way your image colors were distributed ? I have a transparent background. I could exclude the background and do not avarage the background pixels.

Comment: There may not be a "predominant" color per se. Even if all colors are very similar, they could all be slightly different. You could do some sort of [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) or average the hues of everything. I'm not sure how you account for hues wrapping around 360 ° though (e.g. 0==360). Other than that, your method seems solid.

Comment: Check out my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064556/better-image-coloring-logic-algorithm/9075340#9075340) to a similar question.