# change color vector graphics

Tags: html, graphics, vector

On several webpages I have seen graphics where the user can change it's color.

For example I've seen pages where it's possible to change the color of a shirt.

How is this done using HTML5? Do I need a vector image in a special format and how do I change the colors?

Comment: I describe an algorithm [in my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064556/better-image-coloring-logic-algorithm/9075340#9075340). It could probably be adapted for HTML canvas.